# laravel-mix with vue 3 lead to error on render #app with <script> element

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-mix

After migrating laravel project from `vue 2` to `vue 3` and some adopts vue code, all works fine except one problem: error on page that contain any `<script>` element, e.g.:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A1cb2ed31fa7eab72a19e760573665ef5c68b106cc01be55d21487083ad2acd7a&amp;width=500&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

Other pages with vue components works fine, but on page with `script` tag, root vue element `#app` become empty and console shows follow errors:

```
app.js?id=466352a350449eddbbc6:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: 60
    at Hc (app.js?id=161352a39ju49eddbfnh:1)
    at mp (app.js?id=161352a39ju49eddbfnh:1)
    ... 
Script element was removed from document.
```

I use laravel-mix with follow setup:

```js
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue({
        version: 3,
        options: {
            compilerOptions: {
                whitespace: 'preserve',
            },
        },
    })
```

app.js script:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const Vue = createApp({})
Vue.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'
window.vue = Vue.mount('#app')
```

Can i force to keep `<script>` element inside `#app` like in vue 2?
Also interested another fixes of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

please check :

https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/3112#issuecomment-1098962998

And

https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/3112#issuecomment-1098962998

I am having a similar issue and it appears to triggered if there is a `<style>` or `<script>` tag contained within the designated div for your vue application.